# How do physics engines handle weight?

Tags: physics

This is most likely a trivial problem, one that only occurs from my stupidity but... How do physics engines that use vector velocities and coordinates, handle weight? Not just increased gravity that causes all objects on screen to move downwards, but increased gravity around a single point. I've tried just increasing the gravity when an object is moving away, but this creates a very unrealistic effect when objects with large masses move away.

Comment: Do you mean the gravitational force one object imposes on another object?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the engine, but generally speaking, **an object that "should" exert a significant gravitational pull will do so**. It's just another force to add to the equation.

The problem with this is that if you have every object exert a gravitational pull on every other object (as real objects do), **the number of calculations you have to make rises exponentially as you add objects to the system**. There are a number of optimizations that many engines make, sacrificing strict realism to try to get this back under control. Here are a few:

- **Only "significant" objects exert a pull**. A classic example of this would be simulating a solar system: the sun must exhibit a pull, and planets probably do too, but spaceships generally don't. Everything is still subject to pulls, so there's a still a cost for adding "insignificant" objects (one calculation per *significant* object), but it's much lower than for adding significant objects (one calculation for *every* object). If you have a lot of insignificant objects and only a few significant ones, this saves you a lot of time.
- **Objects only exert a pull on "nearby" objects, and ignore distant ones**. Thanks to the inverse-square law, the effects of gravity between two objects becomes very small as they become distant. Eventually, it becomes so small that it becomes safe to ignore for many purposes, and that's exactly what many engines do: establish some cutoff radius beyond which gravity between two objects gets ignored.
- **"Close" objects get clumped together, and their gravitational pull gets combined to deal with "distant" objects**. This lets you get back some of the realism you lose by ignoring gravity between distant objects. Say you have two distant galaxies of 100 stars each: if each one exerted an individual pull on all of the other stars in the system, you'd have to make 10^200 calculations per tick: one for each pair of stars. If you clump them together into two galaxies, you only need 20,001 calculations per tick: 10,000 for galaxy A (100 pairs of stars), 10,000 for galaxy B, and then one for the pull between the two galaxies.